# How to declare variables inside the method (Python)

Tags: python, function, methods

```
def intro():
   print("This program computes payroll based on")
   print("over time rate of ", overTime, " after ", workWeek, " hours")
   name = input("Enter employees name: ")
   hours = (int(input("Enter hours worked: ")))
   rate = input("Enter rate: ")
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - post the actual code.  PLease read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Just paste your code in, mark it and hit the `{ }` button.

Comment: I see no methods here, and furthermore, Python *doesn't have variable declarations*. So what, precisely, is it that you are trying to accomplish? It would be better if you gave an example input, then output, then describe how what you are doing isn't working. If you are getting any errors, please provide the error message and stack trace.

Comment: Why is your code not working? As far as I know, python should look for a variable defined in the function (not method) `run`. It will not find it and it will look for the larger scope. There it should find it and run as expected. Once the variable is set as a consequence of the input, the value become local (accessible only inside the function, while outside of the function still keeping the 'Y' value.
Not particularly elegant, but I don't see why it should fail (if you post the actual code as said above, we can test it).

Answer (score 1):

Whereas it's considered to be a bad practice and in most cases you should avoid using global variables, you can use "global" to reach your variable inside the function.

Like this:

```
global name
name = input("string")
```

Comment: This will certainly be a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Don't do this.  Just return `name`.  Then it will be accessible from the calling code.

Comment: @jedwards Yep, I've never used such a bad code to know this for sure :). Edited the answer anyway